# Creating .pid file that stores user PID

Tags: c

First time publishing here
Simple situation: In PUTTY, i have to create a file named admin.pid where it stores a PID when the user starts the "app" i'm creating. How can i do this? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the "c" tag is really relevant for this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Get the PID using `getpid()`.
2. Open the file using `fopen()`.
3. Write the PID to the file by `fprintf()`.
4. Close the file using `fclose()`.

Comment: if the file already exists, does the OP want to replace the contents or append the new PID.

Comment: append.
Thanks Everyone.